# Posting complex data to MVC 4

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pretty new to MVC 4 and I am trying to get my controller to recieve the post data from the request. It is pretty large and complex. Here is a snippet:

```
Customer.attribute[0].name=TriggerValue
Customer.attribute[0].value=451.51
```

Firebug shows the url encoded like this:

```
Customer.attribute%5B0%5D.name=TriggerValue&Customer.attribute%5B0%5D.value=451.51
```

These data points are posted to to the page, but I am unsure how to get the controller to receive it.

I've done the following with no avail:

```
// the get call 
public virtual ActionResult Alert()
```

Get works fine when you hit the page w/o sending post data so the page works.

```
// the post call?
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult PriceAlert(PostData postdata)
```

for the model postData I have all the elements as strings or ints, or another class for the attribute one i did this:

```
public class customer
{
 ...
 public List<AlertAttribute> attribute { get; set; }
...
}
public class AlertAttribute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I have even tried the below and it also doesn't hit it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PriceAlert(FormCollection fc)
```

Not sure if you need this or not, but when using firebug and looking at the post request the content information is as follows:

```
Content-Length  2313
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

EDIT:
To make this more manageable, I have reduced the post values to try and create a simple posting request.

Model:

```
public class PostData
{
        public string BottomAd { get; set; }
        public string BottomAdLink { get; set; }
        public string BottomRandID { get; set; }


}
```

Controller:

```
    public virtual ActionResult PriceAlert()
    {
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult PriceAlert(PostData postdata)
    {
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PriceAlert(FormCollection fc)
    {
        return View();

    }
```

Post Request:

BottomAd=test&BottomAdLink=test&BottomRandID=test

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Is it that when you post it is not entering the expected POST action?  Is it that it's simply not passing the formcollection data that you expect?

Comment: Can you add the code for the HTML form (the entire code, or at least a higher level view) and the signatures of your actions on that controller?

Comment: It's probably best if you define a model class that is a simplified version of your customer class.  It'll give you tighter control over your post data, and you'll be able to decorate your model with the correct validation attributes.  You couldn't necessarily do this on your customer class.

Comment: Just noticed that the GET method is called `Alert` and the POST is called `PriceAlert`. Unless you specify `PriceAlert` as the post action name in the form helper as in `@using(Html.BeginForm("PriceAlert", "YourControllerName"){` , it will expect the post method being named `Alert`

Comment: @DoctorJones - I will attempt that by limiting my post values, We are migrating from a classic ASP setup to a .net setup and so the values are already defined. but will limit them.

Comment: @Jeff - The problem is the controller is never being hit when i am in debug

Comment: For whatever reason now the FormCollection is working....

Comment: I found out the problem, the issue has nothing to do with signature and everything to do with IIS, i am posting 2313 bytes, when IIS was only allowing 2048. and, now when increasing I get a Request to large error.

Answer (score 0):

Post:

```
Attributes[0].name=TriggerValue
Attributes[0].value=451.51
```

Note that indexes must start at 0 and be sequential, if you only post 0,1 and 5, then 5 will be missed because MVC stops binding lists once there is a gap in the sequence.

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerVM
{
  List<NameValueVM> Attributes {get;set;}
}

public class NameValueVM
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public decimal Value {get;set;}
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public class CustomerController
{
    public ActionResult Save(CustomerVM vm)
    {
        //vm.Attributes should have one item in it

    }
}
```

Comment: No, the indices need not be sequential anymore.

Comment: What you have to have is a hidden field named Attibutes.index with value set to the index.

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr You don't *need* to have a hidden index value, that is another approach but the above will work fine without it.